# Catchable fatal error: Object of class Creator could not be converted to string

Tags: php, class, object, fatal-error

i have this function that insert code in my file.php:

```
function InsertData($nombre, $var1, $var2, $var3)
{
    $file = fopen("$nombre".".php", "r+");
    // Seek to the end
    fseek($file, SEEK_END, 0);
    // Get and save that position
    $filesize = ftell($file);
    // Seek to half the length of the file
    fseek($file, SEEK_SET, $filesize / 1);
    // Write your data
    fwrite($file, "<?php
class " ."$nombre". "\n
{\n
private $" ."$var1;". "\n
private $" ."$var2;". "\n
private $" ."$var3;". "\n
\n\n
    public function __construct()\n
    {\n
        $this->setData($" ."$var1". ", $" ."$var2". ", $" ."$var3". ");\n
        //parent::__construct();\n

    }
\n\n
    public function setData($" ."$var1". ", $" ."$var2". ", $" ."$var3". ")\n
    {\n
        $this->" ."$var1". "= $" ."$var1;". "\n
        $this->" ."$var2". "= $" ."$var2;". "\n
        $this->" ."$var3". "= $" ."$var3;". "\n
    }
\n\n
    public function printData()
    {\n
        echo \"SomeThing : \" . $this->" ."var1". ". \" \" . $this->" ."var2". ".     \"\n\";\n
        echo \"Other : \" . $this->" ."var3". ". \"\n\";\n
    }
\n\n
}
\n\n
?>");
    // Close the file handler
    fclose($file);
}
```

but when i call it i get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class Creator could not be converted to string in create.php on line 37

line 37 is:

```
$this->" ."$var1". "= $" ."$var1;". "\n
```

im calling it like this in other file:

```
$lol = new Creator();
$lol->CreateFile($input);
$lol->InsertData($input, $input1, $input2, $input3);
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: If you are posting about a specific error you **must** include the full error message (with line number) and at least the code on that line and the one before it.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the Creator class?

Comment: sorry, i just updated the post.

the rest of the creator class only have this extra function:

    function CreateFile($nombre)
 {
  $ourFileName = "$nombre".".php";
  $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or     die("can't open file");
  fclose($ourFileHandle);
 }

Comment: It's very difficult to parse what you're writing to that file because you have all your `$var1, $var2, $var3` enclosed in quotes.  If you are writing those to the file interpolated, I would suggest removing the quotes, and also single-quoting the entire string without the `\n` since linebreaks are already embedded.

Comment: At least, unquote the variables that are supposed to be interpolated like `. "$var1" . `

Comment: Also, what is `$input` in the last code block?

Comment: Im trying to write variables in the file.

Comment: $input is going to be the name of the file and the class inside the file.
unquote ? you mean like this: $this->" .$var1. "= $" .$var1. ";\n
if that wath you mean it doesnt work i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong quotes for the whole class you are trying to generate. Try to change double quotes `"` to single quotes `'`. The error is because when you use `"$this"` PHP is trying to call `$this->__toString()`,  in this context is `$this` still a variable from your outside code. Using `'$this'` (in single quotes) is just nothing more than simple string.

Another solution whould be to add backslash before `$this` - `"\$this"`